# Binding an AnalyticMap Model with an OData service in UI5

Tags: javascript, html, sapui5

I'm new to the **UI5** developping tool and I'm trying to bind a colorisation rules function with the regions that compose a map.

The colorization function named `oColor()` is located in the **formatter.js** (that I call through the controller).

The map is successfully drown in the **view.js** (NB : not .XML) using the `sap.ui.vbm.AnalyticMap()` function and a **country.json** file of the concerned era.

The **OData** is set in the `init` section of the **component.js** with the following function:

```
var oModelInputless = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel({
                serviceUrl: "http://server:port/path/Inputless.xsodata",
                json: true,
                defaultBindingMode: sap.ui.model.BindingMode.TwoWay
            });
            sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModelInputless, "/Inputless");
```

It contains an entity named **Data**. The useful properties are named : **id**, **dept** and **ratio**.

I would like to colorize the regions of my Map according to the ratio (which should be recieved as a parametter by the function `oColor()` but I have no idea how to do it.

This is my **view.js:**

```
sap.ui.jsview("package.view.main", {

/* Specifies the Controller belonging to this View. 
 * In the case that it is not implemented, or that "null" is returned, this View does not have a Controller.
 * @memberOf controller.main
 */
getControllerName: function() {
    return "Laposte.controller.main";
},

/* Is initially called once after the Controller has been instantiated. It is the place where the UI is constructed. 
 * Since the Controller is given to this method, its event handlers can be attached right away.
 * @memberOf controller.main
 */
createContent: function(oController) {

    // set the geojson location to some data
    jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.vbm.AnalyticMap");
    // Map GeoJSON
    sap.ui.vbm.AnalyticMap.GeoJSONURL = "./map/country.json";

    var oRegion = new sap.ui.vbm.Region({
        code: "{id}",
        color: {
                parts: [
                    {path: "ratio"}
                ],
                formatter: oController.formatter.oColor
            },
        tooltip: "ratio"
    });

    var oVBI1 = new sap.ui.vbm.AnalyticMap('vbi', {
        width: "100%",
        height: 1000,
        plugin: false,
        centerPosition: "2.2137;46.2276",
        zoomlevel: 6,
        regions : {
                    path : "/Inputless/Data",
                    template: oRegion
                }

    });

    var oPage = new sap.m.Page({
        title: "{i18n>title}",
        content: [oVBI1]
    });

    var app = new sap.m.App("myApp", {
        initialPage: "oPage"
    });
    app.addPage(oPage);
    return app;
  }
});
```

I was told to use the `bindAggregation` method and `parameters : {select DEPT,QSperc}` in the parameter **regions** of my map `oVBI1` but I don't know how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question as I got rid of the problem I've submitted to you:

I had to load everything in the **Component.js** first but not in the **view.js**, this way:

**Component.js:**

```
var oModelInputless = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel("http://server:port/path/Inputless.xsodata",{
    json: true,
    useBatch: false,
    defaultBindingMode: "None"
});
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModelInputless, "Inputless");

//set the device model
this.setModel(models.createDeviceModel(), "device");

//instanciation the map in the Component.js but not in the view
sap.ui.getCore().byId("vbi").setModel(oModelInputless, "Inputless");
sap.ui.getCore().byId("vbi").bindAggregation("regions", {
    path: "Inputless>/Data",
    template: sap.ui.getCore().byId("region"),
    parameters: {
        select: "dpt,ratio"
    }
});
```

**view.js:**

```
/* Specifies the Controller belonging to this View. 
 * In the case that it is not implemented, or that "null" is returned, this View does not have a Controller.
 * @memberOf controller.main
 */
getControllerName: function() {
    return "package.controller.main";
},

/* Is initially called once after the Controller has been instantiated. It is the place where the UI is constructed. 
 * Since the Controller is given to this method, its event handlers can be attached right away.
 * @memberOf controller.main
 */
createContent: function(oController) {

    // set the geojson location to some data
    jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.vbm.AnalyticMap");
    // Map GeoJSON
    sap.ui.vbm.AnalyticMap.GeoJSONURL = "./map/country.json";

    //region template
    var oRegion = new sap.ui.vbm.Region("region", {
        code: "{Inputless>DEPT}",
        color: { // fixé en rajoutant data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex" au index.html
            parts: ["Inputless>QSperc"],
            formatter: oController.formatter.qsColor
        },
        tooltip: "{Inputless>QSperc}"
    });

    var oVBI1 = new sap.ui.vbm.AnalyticMap('vbi', {
        width: "100%",
        height: 1000,
        plugin: false,
        centerPosition: "2.2137;46.2276",
        zoomlevel: 6,
        vos: [oSpots] 
    });
    var oPage = new sap.m.Page({
        title: "{i18n>title}",
        content: [oVBI1]
    });

    var app = new sap.m.App("myApp", {
        initialPage: "oPage"
    });
    app.addPage(oPage);
    return app;
    }
});
```

Hope it helps somebody.